# Sending Autherization crud authorization

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, crud

I am writing (Attempting to write a crud application!)
I need to send a Key to the server before I can start using the service.

```
        this.InitializeComponent();
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://dignity-network.org/api/");
```

I have tried

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("NO3ID81WJECJXZI83A3YYPGJKJLNEJMQ@dignity-network.org/api/")
```

But this does not work, what is the correct request to send authorization to a server ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All depends how the server accepts and implements authorization code.
if you have to send the auth code before you start to use , you just need:

```
HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create(yourAuthCode, Encoding.UTF8);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.Post(new Uri ("http://dignity-network.org/api/"), content);
```

Comment: This is a metro app what do I need to add to the using statements for the above to work ?

Comment: 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Comment: It comes with `HttpMethodExtensions` class http://alexmg.com/post/2009/04/07/Introduction-to-the-HttpClient.aspx

Comment: Most of the functionality has been incorporated into the .NET Framework 4.0, with the notable exception of the HttpClient framework. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/95746c3e-0238-4cf5-9b2e-01e8586c4855